# Who gets the Activity result when an Activity is re-constructed on configuration change?

Tags: android

As I understand it, if I don't explicitly tell Android that I want to handle a configuration change in an Activity, it will get torn down and re-created on, say, an orientation change.

Let's say that I have object O that's an instance of some class `MyCustomClass` in Activity A. When the user presses a button in Activity A's layout, we call `O.startActivityB`. That method will start Activity B. When Activity B gets re-created on an orientation change, I can tell (some flag was set in another or something), so Activity B immediately runs this:

```
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
finish();
return;
```

Who is Activity B's parent activity at this point? Who gets the result code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you started Activity B from Activity A, the 'parent' is Activity A. The fact that an activity gets recreated for some reason doesn't change the activity stack in any way. BTW, if you want to receive a result, you need to use `startActivityForResult()`, not `startActvity()`.

Comment: So, are you saying that because I used `startActivity`, the result is lost?

Comment: Yes. More like not delivered though, not lost.